# Cleaning and stopping spawned actors from inside a service in Xstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state-machine, xstate

I have extensively read the docs, however, there are still some parts that are not entirely clear, and most have to do with actors/services

I am a little fuzzy on the details of spawned actors' lifecycles.

- Will calling `.stop()` on a service with spawned actors also `.stop()` the spawned actors or they are left hanging?
- How should I be clearing spawned actors from a machine? Is there a way to access spawned actors in `children` from inside the service itself? (like from inside an action)

Say I have a machine with an action for adding files. When a file is added a new `spawn()` is called for it, and the reference is stored to the `context`. Now, when the machine finishes whatever it's doing, I want to reset the `context` and clear the `children` after `.stop()`ing each one.

To be completely specific [here](https://xstate.js.org/viz/?gist=055f79a01af232ffd2a29d1af59d236b) is how I have modelled an upload system which implements the behaviour described above.

In this implementation, whenever the machine returns to the `idle` state, I am resetting the `context` and manually `.stop()`ing each spawned actor. However, the actor services are still hanging around in the `.children` and I cannot access them from inside the machine actions (adding the 3rd parameter `meta` to the `resetContext` doesn't lead to anything with access to the current `children`).

Regarding `.stop()`ing the actors and clearing the `children` and resetting the `context`, ideally I would like to have a separate action for each, to be run when `idle` state is entered, however since I cannot seem to find a way to access `children`, doing it all in one action through the `context` is the only solution I could think of.

Also, of note that in the [official example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xstate-todomvc-33wr94qv1) when a todo is deleted its spawned actor is not `.stop()`ed which makes me wonder if it's an oversight or is there a reason?

Below, for your convenience, is the code that implements the upload system and the file. The full implementation, which also includes the vizualizer, can be found [here](https://xstate.js.org/viz/?gist=055f79a01af232ffd2a29d1af59d236b):

```
// upload system machine

const uploadSystemMachine = Machine(
  {
    id: 'upload-system',
    initial: 'idle',
    context: {
      files: [],
      successes: 0,
      failures: 0,
      cancellations: 0,
    },
    states: {
      idle: {
        entry: ['clearSpawnedActors', 'resetContext'],
        on: {
          OPEN: 'active',
        },
      },
      active: {
        initial: 'waitingForFiles',
        states: {
          waitingForFiles: {
            on: {
              CLOSE: {
                target: '#upload-system.idle',
              },
              ADD: {
                actions: 'addFile',
              },
              UPLOAD: {
                target: 'pending',
                cond: 'hasFiles',
              },
            },
          },
          pending: {
            entry: 'startFileUploads',
            on: {
              'FILE.UPLOADED': {
                actions: 'incrementSuccesses',
              },
              'FILE.FAILED': {
                actions: 'incrementFailures',
              },
              'FILE.CANCELLED': {
                actions: 'incrementCancellations',
              },
              CANCEL: {
                actions: 'cancelFileUpload',
              },
              '': {
                target: 'completed',
                cond: 'allSettled',
              },
            },
          },
          completed: {
            type: 'final',
            on: {
              CLOSE: '#upload-system.idle',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    on: {
      KILL: '.idle',
    },
  },
  {
    guards: {
      hasFiles: context => {
        return context.files.length > 0;
      },
      hasNoFiles: context => {
        return context.files.length === 0;
      },
      allSettled: context => {
        return (
          context.files.length === context.successes + context.failures + context.cancellations
        );
      },
    },
    actions: {
      startFileUploads: context => {
        context.files.forEach(actor => {
          actor.send('START');
        });
      },
      addFile: assign({
        files: (context, event) => {
          const newValue = spawn(
            fileMachine.withContext(event.target ? event.target.data : {}),
            context.files.length
          );

          return [...context.files, newValue];
        },
      }),
      resetContext: assign({
        files: context => {
          context.files.forEach(actor => {
            console.log(actor);
            actor.stop();
          });

          return [];
        },
        successes: 0,
        failures: 0,
        cancellations: 0,
      }),
      cancelFileUpload: (context, event) => {
        const fileID = event.data.id;
        for (let i = 0; i < context.files.length; i++) {
          if (context.files[i].id === fileID) {
            context.files[i].send('CANCEL');
            break;
          }
        }
      },
      incrementSuccesses: assign({
        successes: context => {
          return context.successes + 1;
        },
      }),
      incrementFailures: assign({
        failures: context => {
          return context.failures + 1;
        },
      }),
      incrementCancellations: assign({
        cancellations: context => {
          return context.cancellations + 1;
        },
      }),
    },
  }
);
```

```
// file machine

const fileMachine = Machine(
  {
    id: 'file',
    initial: 'idle',
    context: null,
    states: {
      idle: {
        on: {
          START: 'pending',
        },
      },
      pending: {
        invoke: {
          id: 'upload',
          src: 'upload',
        },
        on: {
          RESOLVED: 'success',
          REJECTED: 'failed',
          CANCEL: 'cancelled',
        },
      },
      success: {
        type: 'final',
        entry: [
          () => {
            console.log('%centering file success state', 'color: green');
          },
          sendParent('FILE.UPLOADED'),
        ],
      },
      failed: {
        type: 'final',
        entry: [
          () => {
            console.log('%centering file failed state', 'color: red');
          },
          sendParent('FILE.FAILED'),
        ],
      },
      cancelled: {
        type: 'final',
        entry: [
          () => {
            console.log('%centering file cancelled state', 'color: orange');
          },
          sendParent('FILE.CANCELLED'),
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    services: {
      upload: (__context, event) => {
        return callback => {
          let cancelRequest;
          let settled;
          const req = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            cancelRequest = reject;
            console.log('Started uploading', event);

            return setTimeout(() => {
              const cond = Math.random() > 0.5;

              if (cond) {
                resolve();
              } else {
                reject();
              }
            }, Math.random() * 5000);
          });

          req
            .then(() => {
              settled = true;
              console.log('%cFile uploaded successfully', 'color: green');
              callback('RESOLVED');
            })
            .catch(() => {
              settled = true;
              console.log('%cFile failed to upload', 'color: red');
              callback('REJECTED');
            });

          return () => {
            if (!settled) {
              console.log('canceling request');
              cancelRequest();
            }
          };
        };
      },
    },
  }
);
```